# Alignment in the sentence

Tags: grammar

Sentence: "Are you an Italian speaker who wants to improve your English?"

Question: should I say **improve your English** or **improve their English** in this sentence? I was thinking about dropping "your" but it didn't sound right to me.

Answer (score 1):

Both "your" and "their" are possible.

"... who wants to improve English" is not the right meaning.  It means you want to make the English language better (eg bai fiksing ol dha wiird spelingz)

The interesting thing about the sentence is that you address the person in both the second person "you", and the third person "an Italian speaker".  Moreover the subject of the relative clause "who" seems to refer to the third person "an Italian speaker".  As a result, it would be natural to continue to use the third person at the end: "... his/her English."

But English has gendered pronouns, and you don't want to misgender the person you are addressing, and the usual solution to this is to use the "singular they".  So I would write "... who wants to improve their English".

However, I would happily accept "improve your English", since in this case, the "Italian speaker" is "you".

There is a slight difference in tone between "their" and "your".  Using the third person "their" is a little less personal.